# If $X$ is an orientable connected non compact $n$- manifold then $H_n(X) = 0$

Tags: algebraic-topology, manifolds, homology-cohomology, homological-algebra, poincare-duality

To prove the assert I led back to prove that $H_c^0(X) = 0$ thanks to [Poincarè-duality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poincar%C3%A9_duality), using the fact that $H_c^0(X) = \text{lim}H^0(X,X\setminus K,\mathbb{Z}) = \text{lim} 0 = 0$, since [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4068741/if-varnothing-ne-a-subseteq-x-with-x-path-connected-then-h-0x-a-0) we noticed that $H_0(X,A)= 0$ if $X$ is path connected for every nonempty $A$ (and using universal coefficient theorem for cohomology).

Is the reasoning is correct, one could imply something on $H_c^0(X,G)$ with $G \ne \mathbb{Z}$ or are there counterexample to the fact that $H_n(X,G) \ne 0$ with above hypothesis ?

Comment: Yes, your reasoning is correct.

Comment: @MoisheKohan What about $H(M;G)$?

Comment: It is exactly the same proof, so your reasoning is still correct, as I said.

Comment: @MoisheKohan What's the argument to show that $H_0(X,A;G) =0$ for every $G$ ?

Comment: Constant function equal to zero at some point is identically zero.

Comment: @MoisheKohan $G$ is an abelian group or generic $R-$module ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can prove directly that $H^0_c(X;R)=0$ where $R$ is any commutative ring (or an abelian group). The easiest way to see this is to observe that $H^*_c(X;R)$ can be described as the group of compactly supported cocycles (modulo compactly supported coboundaries). See for instance Hatcher's "Algebraic Topology," section 3.3. No need for direct limits.

In degree zero, coboundaries are irrelevant. If $X$ is path-connected then every compactly-supported degree zero cocycle is zero. Hence, $H^0_c(X;R)=0$.

Lastly, Poincare Duality works with coefficients in any commutative ring, again, see for instance Hatcher's book.